# Djnago. Загрузка блока при значении URL

Tags: python, django

Есть URL hxxp://example.ex/block/ и следующая конструкция в html шаблоне:

```
{% if 'block' in request.path %}
<h1>Title 1</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Из примера понятно, что если в URL присутствует 'block', будет загружаться тэг h1.
Я хочу на этом же шаблоне разместить поиск, который будет выводиться по следующему URL hxxp://example.ex/block/search=result. Но, если написать:

```
{% if 'search' in request.path %}
<h1>Search Title</h1>
{% endif %}
```

На выходе в URL 'hxxp://example.ex/block/search=result' я получаю:

```
Title 1
Search Title
```

Все логично, ведь в URL присутствует и 'block' и 'search'. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно оформить код, чтобы тэг h1 содержал разные значения. 
Возможно я вообще неправильно подхожу к этому вопросу, буду рад любым разъяснениям! Спасибо!

Comment: Самый простой способ - использовать `{% elif %}`. Выглядеть будет примерно так: `{% if 'search' in request.path %}<h1>Search Title</h1>{% elif 'block' in request.path %}<h1>Title 1</h1>{% endif %}`. Но я бы использовал фильтры и вынес бы эту логику за пределы шаблона.

Comment: {% elif %} не работает. Странно, ошибки не выводит, но и значения не меняются.

Comment: Должно работать. На всякий случай приведу документацию, там довольно наглядные примеры: [Built-in template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#if). Там и про фильтры почитать можно.